# How to handle insert/updates and counter with a lot of concurrent users

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, concurrency, redis

I'm writing an API that will have a medium amount of traffic most of the time, but at certain points it will have a lot of concurrent users.
Lets say that the API should be able to handle at least 10 000 requests a second in "burst-mode".

When a request comes in the API need to do 2 things (simplified).
1) Get a counter from database.
2) If counter is under 500 -> insert a new row to database and increase the counter. If the counter have reached 500 return a response without doing insert.

My question is: what is best practice to handle this scenario when I have so many concurrent requests?
I'm thinking about how to ensure that I will NEVER insert more than 500 rows.
How would you design the database?
How to ensure database concurrency?
How to handle that many concurrent users without exploding your server(s)/cloud?
What programming languages should I really not concider (mostly related to what webservers/languages can handle this many req/sec)?

I could go more into detail about hosting, programming language, database choices and caching - but I'm not doing it on purpose.
Lets just say that I'm initially going for heroku or a high-volume digial ocean plan as it comes to hosting, node (with restify) as language, mongo and redis as db/caching - but I want to get some best practices and tips before I go more into detail.

Answer (score 0):

We can't guess much better without touch your application. I am just  suggesting you the a estimate which may not fit in your real situation but you can extend or shrink on the basis of load and response time, data(document size). Its better to use wired Tiger Storage engine instead of Mmapv1 due to document level locking for concurrent writes.

If you have more concurrent read requests and less concurrent writes as you said (total 500 in a day is not painful) but not much concurrent, then replication (1 master and 2 slave) would be enough.

If you have much write requests concurrently (20 to 50) then it may slow down reads, so you can use sharding. (3 shards and each have 1 replica, 3 config server, 3 mongos running on each replica).

As you increasing your writes requests you can increase shards and for read request you can increase replicas. But its better to take maximum best configuration  for NoSql type databases and you know in future data will be increasing fastly. If you don't care about that you will have to pay efforts for management of Database servers, this may cost your application performance also some time.

Comment: Hello!
The writes will also be while the API is in "burst mode". But there are a lot more reads than writes. Lets say the burst mode lasts 5 seconds. The API should then handle 50 000 reads (which I plan to cache) and 500 writes. So the writes are also in a few seconds, not spread through the day.
The most important thing is that I never do more than 500 writes (this is a hard limit that may vary from 200 to 1500 depending on some config parameter from day to day).

I will look into the WiredTiger storage.

Comment: @mario As you said reads are much, i think you can add 1 more replica for shards. But for writes there are 3 shards are enough for 500 writes.